# Print the duplicate lines in a file using awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a requirement to print all the duplicated lines in a file where in `uniq -D` option did not support. So I am thinking of an alternative way to print the duplicate lines using awk. I know that, we have an option in awk like below.

testfile.txt

```
apple
apple
orange
orange
cherry
cherry
kiwi
strawberry
strawberry
papaya
cashew
cashew
pista
```

The command:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++' testfile.txt
```

But the above does print only the unique duplicate lines. I need the same output that `uniq -D` command retrieves like this.

```
apple
apple
orange
orange
cherry
cherry
strawberry
strawberry
cashew
cashew
```

Comment: Why not using `uniq -D` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl For example, Mac terminal does not support `uniq -D`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to stick with just plain awk, you'll have to process the file twice: once to generate the counts, once to eliminate the lines with count equal 1:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {count[$0]++; next} count[$0]>1' testfile.txt testfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot glenn, it did worked perfectly, this is what i exactly looking for.

Comment: @user3834663  Mine works with just plain awk without processing the file twice and I posted it 10 minutes earlier :P

Comment: @CharlieMartin, same comment I made on Ed's answer: this will preserve the order of the original file. Example, try with `printf "%s\n" 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 > file`

Comment: @glennjackman True. Not sure if that was a requirement but fair enough. I was just joking around anyway. My solution is kind of long and brute

Answer (score 17):

No need to parse the file twice:

```
$ awk 'c[$0]++; c[$0]==2' file
apple
apple
orange
orange
cherry
cherry
strawberry
strawberry
cashew
cashew
```

Comment: Clever. May not preserve original order if the file is not sorted or the lines aren't grouped already

Comment: @glennjackman correct. The OP did say they need the same behavior as from `uniq -D` which does require the duplicate lines to be adjacent as shown in the sample input/output but if the OP has a situation where they aren't then (s)she should obviously include it in the sample input/output and let us know.

Comment: ```awk 'c[$0]++ && c[$0]==2' file``` for outputting every duplicate only once

Comment: This still works when there are more than two in a duplicated series. For example, if "foo" is repeated twice or more, "foo" #1 is not printed. "foo" #2 is printed twice (once by `c[$0]++`, once by `c[$0]==2`. "foo" #3 and onward are each printed once by `c[$0]++`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed 'N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/p;$d;D' testfile.txt
apple
apple
orange
orange
cherry
cherry
strawberry
strawberry
cashew
cashew
```

This does the following:

```
N                 # Append next line to pattern space
/^\(.*\)\n\1$/p   # Print if lines in pattern space are identical
$d                # Avoid printing lone non-duplicate last line
D                 # Delete first line in pattern space
```

There are a few limitations:

- It only works for contiguous duplicates, i.e., not for

  ```
  apple
  orange
  apple
  ```
- Lines appearing more than twice in a row throw it off.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn ':a;N;/^([^\n]*)\n\1$/p;//ba;/^([^\n]*)(\n\1)+$/P;//ba;s/.*\n//;ba' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space (PS). If the first two lines are duplicate, print them and loop back and read a third line. If the third or subsequent lines are duplicate, print the first and loop back and read another line. Otherwise, remove all but the last line and loop back and read another etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, if uniq supports `-d`?

```
grep -f <(uniq -d testfile.txt ) testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if (x[$1]) { x_count[$1]++; print $0; if (x_count[$1] == 1) { print x[$1] } } x[$1] = $0}' testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$ uniq -d file | awk '1;1'
```